# java , oracle - prepared statement ORA-00936

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement

I've this simple piece of code in a Java Class.

I've to query the DB looking for a text match.

I think the problem is in the second '?' but I can't understandy why.

```java
        int userID = this.userID;
        String filter = this.filter;

        PreparedStatement stmt;
        ResultSet rset1;
        String query1
                = selectMediaList
                + "FROM "
                + schema + ".MEDIA M"
                + " WHERE M.USER_ID = ?"
                + " AND LIKE REGEXP_LIKE ( M.TITLE , ? ) ";


        stmt = connection.prepareStatement ( query1, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        stmt.setInt ( 1, userID );
        stmt.setString ( 2, filter );
        rset1 = stmt.executeQuery ();
```

but I got always this SQL exception:
ORA-00936: missing expression

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a typo, you need to remove `LIKE `. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 4):

Change :

```
 + " AND LIKE REGEXP_LIKE ( M.TITLE , ? ) ";
```

To:

```
+ " AND REGEXP_LIKE ( M.TITLE , ? ) ";
```

Think `like` is not nessesary if you use `REGEXP_LIKE`.

Comment: Well, I'm an Idiot. I didn't see the 1st Like